# Container for interpolating T along axis of numerical keys

Tags: c++, c++17, game-development

Is there a container that when inialized with a key1 at 10 and key2 at 20, when accessed at 15 will call an interpolation callback function with (key1, key2, 0.5) with return value T?

The callback ensures that we can use our preferred S-curve for the interpolation. I'm expecting accesses on each end to pass the same key in both with 1.0 as the factor.

Pseudo-code:

```
Container<float, MyStruct> container;
container.insert(10, MyStruct{  .x = 1.0f  });
container.insert(20, MyStruct{  .x = 2.0f  });

auto middlepoint = container.get(15,
    [] (const MyStruct& a, const MyStruct& b, float factor) {
        return MyStruct{ a.x * factor + b.x * (1.0 - factor) };
    });
assert(middlepoint.x ~ 1.5f);
```

Have you seen this? What is this data structure called?

Thanks

Comment: There's no such container in the C++ library, that does everything. You will need to start with one of the ordered containers, like `std::map`, or even a sorted `std::vector`, then use `std::lower_bound` and/or `std::upper_bound` to implement the rest of this functionality.

Comment: looks like a `std::map` + finding the correct interval + calling the interpolation function

Comment: asking for libraries is offtopic. Anyhow, maybe its a wheel, but a not too complicated one. I'd expect a couple of lines of code to be sufficient

Comment: It seems you know how to implement it directly. Notice that this is not a question about a Data-Structure, thus, there should be no basic container that does such a thing. It seems like an operation using a DS and not something that it should contain on its own.

Comment: I was actually asking if this data structure had a name, but I guess not. I will try to look for "wheel" and see what I get. I've implemented this before, of course, using simple arrays, but it's nice to have some well thought out API when that is available.